# Position an image and two labels in a WKInterfaceTable row

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacelabel

I'm building a watch kit extension for my app that includes a `WKInterfaceTable`. Now I'd like to add a detailTextLabel to the row and place it under the main label. I don't know why but I can only drag it next to the main label not under the primary label. 
Does someone know why and how I can solve it? I just want to display a detailTextLabel like in the iOS app. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table row controller contains a `WKInterfaceGroup` which contains your both `WKInterfaceLabels`. You have to select `Vertical` as the `WKInterfaceGroup's` `Layout` attribute to put the labels on top of each other.

[image][image]

**UPDATE:**

To add a WKInterfaceImage on the left side of your labels you have to use the following setup:

[image]

You need to set the following values:

**Group1:**

- Layout: *Horizontal*
- Height: *Size To Fit Content*

**Image:**

- Size: *Relative To Container*, Factor: *0,3*

**Group2:**

- Layout: *Vertical*
- Size: *Relative To Container*, Factor: *0,7*

**Labels:**

- Width: *Relative to Container*, Factor: *1*

You probably have to play around with the Size factors of the image and the labels group. The sum of these two width factors has to be 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I also have an image view which should be displayed next to the 2 labels. This doesn't work right?

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Is there also a `label.hidden` to hide a label? The 2nd label should be displayed every time so I can hide it if it's possible.

Comment: Yes. All classes that are subclasses of `WKInterfaceObject` have `setHidden` and `setAlpha` methods that you can use to hide interface objects.